# Arduino Reading floating point numbers with sscanf

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

am trying to read numbers with sscanf() but i have no success with double vars but  can read int

example of double

```
//double var reading not working 
    const char KBuffer[80] = "0x3:2.1:2.1:2.1";

    int rt;
    double p,i,d;
    int n = sscanf(KBuffer, "%x:%lf:%lf:%lf", &rt, &p, &i, &d);

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("rt "); Serial.print(rt);
    Serial.print(" P ");Serial.print(p);
    Serial.print(" i ");Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" d ");Serial.print(d);
```

// output
rt 3 P 0.00 i ovf d 0.00

example of int

```
// int reading working ok
    const char KBuffer[80] = "0x3:2:2:2";

    int rt;
    int p,i,d;
    int n = sscanf(KBuffer, "%x:%d:%d:%d", &rt, &p, &i, &d);

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("rt "); Serial.print(rt);
    Serial.print(" P ");Serial.print(p);
    Serial.print(" i ");Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" d ");Serial.print(d);
 // output
rt 3 P 2 i 2 i 2
```

so any idea what am doing wrong

the same code when i run on c++ online compiler like : https://onlinegdb.com/ryS8zfE3r

am getting correct results

Comment: `"%d:%lf:%lf:%lf"` -> `"%x:%lf:%lf:%lf"`

Comment: @Jabberwocky I afraid not enough

Comment: @Jabberwocky ya i updated it , it was bit mistake but issue is same

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The Arduino language is a C++ compiler with C++ syntax and non-standard library.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it is C++ variation without 90% of C++ - very limited support for standard C++ lib

Comment: @P__J__ but it is even less C than C++ ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala actually more C stdlib than C++. take a look inside

Comment: Like methods, overloaded `print` function...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if the first conversion goes well arduino scanf will not read the float numbers and printf will not print them as well. scanf and printf family functions do not support float numbers by default.

the fist problem is easily sortable: `int n = sscanf(KBuffer, "0x%x:%d:%d:%d", &rt, &p, &i, &d);` the second requires changing the compiler (or linker) oprions by adding `-Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt -lm`  But irt will increase the image size by about 15kb.

Read more in `hardware/tools/avr/doc/avr-libc/group__avr__stdio.html` in the directory where your board libraries are installed

Answer (score -1):

after spending sometime i came to conclusion that sscanf cant handle float/double values so  to solve the problem of float input through serial communication i adopted another approach , am sharing it might help someone

```
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
char KBuffer[80] = "c:0x3;p:2.12;i:2.15;d:2.17";

bool top_pid_input = false;

// Read each command pair
char* command = strtok(KBuffer, ";");
while (command != NULL)
{  
//  Serial.print(command);
    // Split the command in two values
    char* separator = strchr(command, ':');
    if (separator != 0)
    {
       // Actually split the string in 2: replace ':' with 0
      *separator = 0;

        // string
         if(strcmp(command, "c") == 0 ){
            top_pid_input = true;
            Serial.println();Serial.print(" command: ");Serial.print(command);
            ++separator;
            Serial.print(separator);
         }else if(top_pid_input && strcmp(command, "p") == 0 ){
            Serial.println();Serial.print(" p: ");Serial.print(command);
            ++separator;
            Serial.print(separator);        
        }else if(top_pid_input && strcmp(command, "i") == 0 ){
            Serial.println();Serial.print(" i: ");Serial.print(command);
            ++separator;
            Serial.print(separator);          
        }else if(top_pid_input && strcmp(command, "d") == 0 ){
            Serial.println();Serial.print(" d: ");Serial.print(command);
            ++separator;
            Serial.print(separator);         
        }

     // convert char to float 
     top_kd = atof(separator);  

    }
    // Find the next command in input string
    command = strtok(0, ";");
}



delay(300000);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT: the question has been edited, so this answer is not longer relevant.**

According to [man pages](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) for `scanf()` family functions:

> Return value These functions return the number of input items
>   successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided
>   for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.

You should check for the returned value, `n` in your code, to see if conversions failed or not.

Here, the first conversion fails: `%d` cannot read hexadecimal numbers. From man page again:

> d
>
> Matches an optionally signed decimal integer; the next pointer must be
>   a pointer to int.

You must use `%x` instead:

> x
>
> Matches an unsigned hexadecimal integer; the next pointer must be a
>   pointer to unsigned int.

Because the first conversion fail, the other conversions are not performed.

Comment: @P__J__ can you explain?

Comment: @Jabberwocky see my answer

Comment: You have you seen the original version of the question? Format used `%d` instead of `%x` so `rt` was 0 because the first conversion failed. What you describe isn't a not conformant behavior. Additional link flags is often needed for floats in embedded systems. But adding those flags won't make the original code IMO.